# when MS DTC is not used in a message queue transaction

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, msmq, msdtc

I'm creating a design to process a large number of jobs using `MSMQ` to scale out. Each job is processed and the database is updated for that job Id saying it is complete. If error, it should go back to the queue. So, I need a `transactional MSMQ`. Now, I could process the job and updating the db record might fail for whatever reason. In this case also, I would need the job back in the queue so it can be re-attempted and saved back to db with success. This means I will need to enable `MS DTC` to manage transaction across the database server.

I am reading `Pro MSMQ` book and it mentions "For most applications, transactions are not needed at all. There is a tendency to overuse transactions and affect the performance of the entire system unnecessarily. Before deciding to use transactions, analyze the `ACID` properties requirement of the entire system and the performance impact.".

I'm failing to understand which cases would not involve a `database` update. Wouldn't any record that is picked up from a queue needs to be processed and updated somewhere? I would think about 90% of the systems will need this type of functionality. I get it if it was a middle layer queue that passes it to another queue or something like that, but for processing the last record in the pipeline, isn't `MS DTC` always required?

Thoughts?

Edit:- the full text:

> Transactional messaging offers a lot of benefits, such as message
>   integrity and  message order, over nontransactional messaging, but the
>   performance price  you pay for using transactional messaging is huge.
>   Use internal transactions  only if it is absolutely essential to
>   maintain the order of messages in the queue.  External transactions
>   offer the benefit of propagating the transaction context  across
>   multiple resource managers. Such transactions are useful when there is
>   a large-scale distributed system with multiple databases and message
>   queues,  and the transactional integrity between the messages
>   exchanged between these  resource managers is critical. The overhead
>   incurred while using external transactions is significantly more
>   than the one incurred by internal Message Queuing  transactions. For
>   most applications, transactions are not needed at all. There  is a
>   tendency to overuse transactions and affect the performance of the
>   entire  system unnecessarily. Before deciding to use transactions,
>   analyze the ACID  properties requirement of the entire system and the
>   resulting performance impact.

Comment: `There is a tendency to overuse transactions` seems an odd statement. Why would anyone use transactions unless there's a requirement for integrity across systems/entities.

Comment: that's kind of my point. When would there be not a requirement for integrity. I mean, you picked up a message from a queue. In what scenario is failing to process and discarding it is ok, especially in larger systems where everything is automated.

Answer (score 0):

As the book says, the main problem with enlisting in these transactions is that you are sacrificing performance at high volumes by locking multiple resources. There are alternative ways for you to achieve your goals without losing consistency. There is always a trade-off between consistency, availability and partition tolerance (read about the [CAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) theorem) and you need to decide which attributes of the system are needed to successfully meet the business requirements.

To tackle your problem without a transaction, instead of popping the message off the queue, you can [Peek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.peek(v=vs.110).aspx) the message, and if your processing succeeds you pop the message and discard it. If the processing fails you move the message to an error queue. Error queues can be automatically retried (it could be a transitory issue). The error queue(s) should be monitored actively to ensure your system is processing correctly, ie. you need alerts to fire if the error queue is over a threshold or increasing at a rate.

Note that this approach won't work for a single queue with multiple processors as you have commented. This will work where you partition your data and messages and bind a processor to a queue.

E.g. I'm doing central sales processing for a chain of retailers. I might say that I process us east coast retailers on queue QA and west coast on queue QB. I have a processor PA bound queue QA (can be muliple exe's or threads in a single exe) and processor PB bound to QB. This way messages are processed in order for a distinct entity in the system.

The key is to pick the right data partitioning scheme so that work is spread evenly.

Comment: peeking wont work correctly if there are multiple handlers. They will be processing the same record potentially thus not yielding best performance and also duplicating results.

Comment: You are correct if you're thinking 1 queue and multiple processors. I'm thinking multiple queues and a processor bound to a queue. I will edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: the problem is most likely you will have to scale this out eventually. So this solution won't work if you tie it to a single processor.

Comment: The whole point of this is to scale out , as per your question. As I said already one processor does not work.

Comment: Yes, but as per your example, it is still one processor for one Queue (QA). I may need more.